# How to design an interface of a function taking data.frame with certain columns?

Tags: r

I am writing an R package and my function should take a data.frame, which has 3 columns - exID, site, occasion. However, I am aware that everyone will have their data with different column names. I am considering several options:

1. The user would have to construct a data.frame with my exact column names, e.g. like this:

   `f(data.frame(exID = mydata$ID, site = mydata$siteID, occasion = mydata$year))`
2. The user would pass his whole data.frame, telling me names of his columns. E.g. like this - feels a bit clumsy:

   `f(mydata, exID.name = "ID", site.name = "siteID", occasion.name = "year")`
3. The user would pass the three vectors:

   `f(exID = mydata$ID, site = mydata$siteID, occasion = mydata$year)`

   But this variant has disadvantages: it might not be apparent to the user that these should be three columns of the same data.frame, and that these values are kind of tied together in this manner. I would have to check if the vectors are of the same length.

Currently, I see the least amount of flaws in the first option. Is there some other option? What are the preferred practices of well established R packages? I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I want to use something people are already used to.

PS: I also considered a solution to supply a formula as an argument, but this seems a bit superfluous and artificial in my case, because the meaning of these three columns is fixed, and formula provides too much freedom there.

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close the question since the answer might be (I) opinion-based and (II) heavily dependent on many factors. Some potential factors: Where does the data.frame come from? would it usually be the result of another function of your package or a stand-alone function that transforms data.frames, e.g. like `melt`? Do you plan to add something to the data.frame, i.e. the function would return the same data structure, Is it transforming it, or does it use the data.frame as an input to do something in combination with another input?

Comment: 1) The data.frame is typically some primary data the user has, i.e. not result of another function. 2) Not sure if I understood the question, but I think the answer is no. 3) The function will be transforming it, but in some cases also in combination with another input, if it is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a matter of taste but Option 2 - provide the data.frame as one object and let the user specify the correct variables by their names as strings - or using a formula is the way this is handled by both base R functions like `lm`, `reshape` and `merge`, {data.table}s `melt`/`dcast`, {tidyr}s `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`.

I would not recommend Option 1 since this requires making a copy of the data. Furthermore, it is harder to use in flexible code.

Comment: Thanks. 1) What do you mean by "it is harder to use in flexible code"?  2) Which ones of these functions correspond to the Option 1?